# session variable not set first time but if reloaded it is set

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have 2 files.

1. Home.php
2. some_func.php

I am setting a session variable in home.php and I am having an ajax call to some_func.php on button click.

Issue:

When I load the page for the first time, the session variable is set in home.php but the same is not reflected in some_func.php  and if I reload home.php and then after that the session variable value is reflected in some_func.php.

I don't know why the session variable value is not getting reflected when I load home.php for the first time.

I have found that this is happening only on my live server and not on my localhost.

Please help.

```
<?php
//home.php file
session_start();
include 'db.inc.php';
$db =  mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD) or die('Unable to connect. Check connection parameters');
mysql_select_db(MYSQL_DB, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

//Checking what is the latest session id available available in my db.
$query = "SELECT max(ses_id) as max_ses_id FROM `dyn_sess` ";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $_SESSION['curr_sess'] = $row['max_ses_id']+1; 
}

echo '<script> alert("Your Session ID : '.$_SESSION['curr_sess'].'");</script>';
?>

<html lang="en">    
<head>    
</head>

<body>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function call_some_func()
            {
                $.post('some_func.php');

            }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="PREV" onClick=call_some_func()>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php
//some_func.php
    session_start();
    require_once('lib/something.php');
    // some php code here.
    // No sessions variable are set. But the session variable curr_sess is used to call an api and that goes as blank for the first time.
    //If I reload home.php it works fine then after from the second time.
?>

<html>
<script> alert(<?php echo $_SESSION['curr_sess'] ?>); </script>
</html>
```

Comment: do u start session? ie session_start(); in some_func.php

Comment: Yes I do. I have it as the very first line in some_func.php

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @user1844933 check out my code.

Comment: Do you see the message `Your Session ID :` with no value ?

Comment: I am just displaying the value of $_SESSION['curr_sess']

Comment: So you are not running the code you pasted in here?? Because that does a `echo '<script> alert("Your Session ID : '.$_SESSION['curr_sess'].'");</script>';` al be it that its echoed before the `<html>` tag which is dodgy at best

Comment: in home.php I see. But in some_func.php I don't for the first time only.  that is: just get blank. i.e. session variable value is not set

Comment: When you run home.php, is you `dyn_sess` table empty? Because if it is your query will return `NULL` which wont show up in a echo as anything.

Comment: Though its dodgy! It works. I dont see any problem in home.php code... The problem is something with some_func.php or the way I call it...

Comment: Try changing the `echo` to a `print_r($_SESSION)`.

Comment: Nope table not empty. It has values.

Comment: point is not about printing the value. The session variable value set in home.php is not getting reflected in some_func.php. For the first time only. That's my question.

Comment: Yes but that would show you if the variable exists and is empty or does not exists at all.

Comment: The variable value shows up every time in home.php. There is no problem with that.

Comment: it seems that your code have no problem at all

Comment: Yeah its working fine on my localhost. I am really not sure whats going wrong with the server. I should start hacking on the server response from now :(